# Rotate animation with scale Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to rotate an image while its size is growing, every thing should be animation. 
Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: how you are increasing your size of image...?

Comment: yes I want to scale it big as well as rotate along

Answer (score 3):

This will scale your image to double size and rotate it 90 degrees, in 5 seconds:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, (CGFloat)(M_PI / 2.0f));

    myImageView.transform = transform;
}];
```